# Use XSLT 1.0 to create a new element and element value from the XML route element name

Tags: xml, xslt

I have lots of different **XML 1.0** responses coming into our CRM system and I need to be able to define the different types of responses received from **API** calls, I need to be able to determine what they are from XML element values. Due to limitations with our CRM system I wanted to explore using **XSLT 1.0** to create a new XML element and use the root XML element name to populate the value of the new element.

**INITIAL XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IRChangePaymentMethod Module="">
   <CtxActRef>12345678</CtxActRef>
   <Header>
      <OrgCode>01</OrgCode>
      <Security>
         <SourceID>TestPortal</SourceID>
      </Security>
      <SupplementaryInformation />
      <System>NDR</System>
   </Header>
   <ProcessNumber />
</IRChangePaymentMethod>
```

**DESIRED XML TRANSFORMATION**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IRChangePaymentMethod Module="">
   <Service>IRChangePaymentMethod</Service>
   <CtxActRef>12345678</CtxActRef>
   <Header>
      <OrgCode>01</OrgCode>
      <Security>
         <SourceID>TestPortal</SourceID>
      </Security>
      <SupplementaryInformation />
      <System>NDR</System>
   </Header>
   <ProcessNumber />
</IRChangePaymentMethod>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems rather trivial:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <Service>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </Service>
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```